# How to change Widget.Toolbar theme programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

```
 toolbar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.ToolBarStyleDark);
```

This is the code I use in `onCreate`. 
The result i get looks like this

[image]

It somehow only changes the textbackground and not the entire toolbar background. 
Calling super.setTheme(darkmode ? R.style.AppTheme : R.style.DarkTheme);
changes the app theme perfectly but doesnt work for toolbar somehow.

This is the style for the toolbar XML:

```
 <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
<style name="ToolBarStyleDark" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary2</item>

</style>
```

and this is the toolbar defined in activity_main.xml

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/copy"
        android:onClick="showView"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />


    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Changing the App:theme manually works as expected, but with code it bugs.

Comment: Looks like  toolbar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimary); after chaning the theme fixed it.